# Singularities of $\,\mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity, entire-functions

It is clear to me that $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, since it has infinitely many terms in Laurent Series expansion principle part.

I was quite sure about my question as well, till I found some text saying that $e^{-1/z^2}$ doesn't have a singularity at all.
How could this be possible, Laurent Series should work here also. Or may be texts are wrong that I found.

Kindly help thanx and regards.

Comment: $\exp(-1/z^2)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, just like $\exp(1/z)$ does.

Comment: Yes! I have a same feeling so that means , those texts are actually @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $f$ is restricted in the real line, and we set $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is $C^\infty$, but NOT real analytic (i.e., expressible as a power series).

However, in $\mathbb C$ it DOES have an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: Thanx ..I agree upon it now.